# does set.pop() really remove arbitrary value?

Tags: python-3.x, set

```py
lis1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
set1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
print(lis1.pop())
print(set1.pop())
```

```
6
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In the case of list , it printed the last value
but in set , it printed the first
also I know that u will say it's unordered
but if u run this program several times
still the result will not change
Does the set of numbers remains unchanged in terms of order?

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the set, you can start feeling some "arbitrary" behaviour:

```
>>> set1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
>>> set1
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> set1.pop()
1
>>> set1.add(1)
>>> set1
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}   # 1 still appears to be "first" in the set, but ... 
>>> set1.pop()
2
```